# tail -f executed of ssh repeat output multiple times

Tags: ssh, tail, mobaxterm

I am trying to monitor a file remotely. Since I cannot install additional useful applications on the source I plan to use `tail` over `ssh` to bring the information local where I have more options.

Since I'm only interested in the last line I also use `-n 1`.

Testing the command without any piping or redirection (that'll come later):

```
ssh serverhost tail -fn 1 /var/log/somelog.log
```

Running this I get the expected output. However, any subsequent tail updates will produce multiple output lines.

e.g.

test file:

```
this is line 1  
this is line 2  
this is line 3
```

On client side run`ssh serverhost tail -fn 1 /var/log/somelog.log`

Output:

```
this is line 3
```

On server side `echo this is line 4 >> /var/log/somelog.log`

On client side output:

```
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 4
this is line 4
this is line 4
```

As a test I redirected the output to a file locally. In that case, I get one line in the file and one less line in the local console output.

I tested this from and to different client-server combinations and so far I can only replicate this from MobaXterm to SLES 12 SP1.

The question is, before I call this a bug, are there any settings on either side that may cause such behaviour?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Which OS (both sides)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I don't understand "upon execution". With -f, the tail does not terminate, so that ssh still runs. Surely, you end up with 4 ssh/tails running, and get the same line reported 4 times.

Comment: @roaima I updated the question with the information.

The question is, before I call this a bug, are there any settings on either side that may cause such behaviour?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Execute = run = "enter command line and press enter". I changed the text to not use the word "execute" so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: @pLumo. Thanks for the reminder. I should know better. MobaXterm to SLES 12 SP1 i.e. Windows to SUSE.

Comment: Please check how many `tail` processes you have running on the remote system. Does it match the expected number? I wonder if there is a rogue process still running from an earlier session